# Grunt require(filename) case sensitivity but windows filenames are case insensitivity

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, gruntjs, grunt-cli

When I try to run grunt command for a UI project in windows, It doesn't throw any error related to .js file names where as it does it linux machines.

eg.
No such file or directory, open '/......Abc.js

How do I make sure to get the same error here in windows machine as well?

Comment: The issue is that it's just not an error on windows. However, I found [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/force-case-sensitivity-webpack-plugin) that could help. I've never used it but maybe it can help.

Comment: Tried but It didn't work.

Comment: I'd say you're just going to have to live with it then, make sure it's in your coding practice to use the proper case. Automated testing and developing on a similar platform to what you deploy to can and will help greatly.

Comment: If you're doing your development on a platform that isn't case sensitive, it's just not case sensitive. I always try to develop in an environment that is close to production, it helps a lot with these "it works on my machine" bugs. As well, automated testing through a CI server running an identical environment to production before deploying helps even more.

That's the best I've got for you.